# Replicate Angular Material design font specification in CSS

Tags: html, css, angular-material

Angular material design specification says that it uses 54% black color for table header. How to set that in CSS?

Reference for specification: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reference:** https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.toolbar

The Material Angular official documentation's code below:

[image]

The `54%` here is referred to the `opacity` of the text which is confirmed by the official documentation code. You can implement it in CSS with the following:

```css
.black-54 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="black-54">I am 54% Black</div>
```

Comment: thanks..can you also help me with what is mean by 13sp font..is it a 13px.